# MudTreeView - How to change checkbox size and color?

Tags: c#, css, blazor, mudblazor

I'm using a CSS framework for Blazor WebAssembly called Mudblazor.
[Link to mudblazor](https://mudblazor.com)

I can not figure out how to set the size and color of the checkbox in MudTreeView.

```
<MudTreeViewItem  Value="@item.CategoryName" Class="mud-treeview-item-content.mud-treeview-item-activated" Selected="item.IsChecked" SelectedChanged="eventArgs => {  CheckboxClicked(item.CategoryId, eventArgs); }" >
```

In Mudblazor using MudCheckBox, you can set size by adding `Size = "Size.Large"` and color: `Color="Color.Primary"` but I do not get it in MudTreeView.

Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround you could add a class to the `MudTreeViewItem` elements that you want to style the checkbox of:

```
<MudTreeViewItem Value='"Name"' Class="custom-treeview-item"/>
```

Then you can use this class to target the checkbox in your css:

```
.custom-treeview-item .mud-checkbox span {
    color: var(--mud-palette-primary);
}

.custom-treeview-item .mud-checkbox svg {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
}
```